# Converting Observable notebook code to plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, observable, contour

I am trying to convert observable notebook from below link to plain Javascript.

https://observablehq.com/@d3/contours

Is there a way to achieve it

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here it is:

```js
const width = 600;
const height = 600;

const value = (x, y) => (1 + (x + y + 1) ** 2 * (19 - 14 * x + 3 * x ** 2 - 14 * y + 6 * x * y + 3 * y ** 2)) * (30 + (2 * x - 3 * y) ** 2 * (18 - 32 * x + 12 * x * x + 48 * y - 36 * x * y + 27 * y ** 2));

const x = d3.scaleLinear([-2, 2], [0, width + 28])
const y = d3.scaleLinear([-2, 1], [height, 0])


const getGrid = () => {
  const q = 4; // The level of detail, e.g., sample every 4 pixels in x and y.
  const x0 = -q / 2, x1 = width + 28 + q;
  const y0 = -q / 2, y1 = height + q;
  const n = Math.ceil((x1 - x0) / q);
  const m = Math.ceil((y1 - y0) / q);
  const grid = new Array(n * m);
  for (let j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
    for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      grid[j * n + i] = value(x.invert(i * q + x0), y.invert(j * q + y0));
    }
  }
  grid.x = -q;
  grid.y = -q;
  grid.k = q;
  grid.n = n;
  grid.m = m;
  return grid;
};

const grid = getGrid();

 
const chart = () => {
    const svg = d3.select("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width + 28, height]);
      
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "#fff")
      .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.5)
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(contours)
    .join("path")
      .attr("fill", d => color(d.value))
      .attr("d", d3.geoPath());

  svg.append("g")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .call(yAxis);

  return svg.node();
} 

const thresholds = d3.range(1, 20).map(i => Math.pow(2, i));

const color = d3.scaleSequentialLog(d3.extent(thresholds), d3.interpolateMagma);



const transform = ({type, value, coordinates}) => {
  return {type, value, coordinates: coordinates.map(rings => {
    return rings.map(points => {
      return points.map(([x, y]) => ([
        grid.x + grid.k * x,
        grid.y + grid.k * y
      ]));
    });
  })};
}
 
 
const contours = d3.contours()
    .size([grid.n, grid.m])
    .thresholds(thresholds)
  (grid)
    .map(transform)
    
const xAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", `translate(0,${height})`)
    .call(d3.axisTop(x).ticks(width / height * 10))
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
    .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick").filter(d => x.domain().includes(d)).remove())
    
const yAxis = g => g
    .attr("transform", "translate(-1,0)")
    .call(d3.axisRight(y))
    .call(g => g.select(".domain").remove())
    .call(g => g.selectAll(".tick").filter(d => y.domain().includes(d)).remove())    
    
chart();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.6.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="300" />
```